# python : How to add values from a dictionary and append a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder how to add a value from the input() to a list. 
The input should match `d.values`

Code:

```
def check():
    d = {'Pizza-Season':'12','Pizza-garlic':'11',
    'Pizza-terranova':'13','Pizza-ham':'10',
    'lasagnes':'14','tiramisu':'8','gelati':'7'}
    addi = 0
    insert = (input('your choice? :'))
    for v in d.values():
        addi.append(insert)
    print(addi)
check()
```

Comment: Please re-take the intro tour, especially [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Collating a series of things into a list is covered quite well in available tutorials.  Also, you're trying to append things to an integer, which is illegal.  You neglected to show your current results (run-time error) and expected results, or to provide the required input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do it like this:

```
def check():
    d = {'Pizza-Season':'12','Pizza-garlic':'11',
    'Pizza-terranova':'13','Pizza-ham':'10',
    'lasagnes':'14','tiramisu':'8','gelati':'7'}
    addi = []
    insert = (input('your choice? :'))
    for v in d.values():
        if v==insert:
            addi.append(insert)
print(addi)
```

The thing is you don't verify if the input is equal to one of the values so you can add it.

A more nice way to do it is like this:

```
if insert in d.values(): addi.append(insert)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's that what are you looking for?

```
d = {'Pizza-Season': '12', 'Pizza-garlic': '11', 'Pizza-terranova': '13', 'Pizza-ham': '10', 'lasagnes': '14', 'tiramisu': '8', 'gelati': '7'}
addi = []

def check():
    insert = (input('your choice? :'))
    if insert in d.keys():
        addi = insert
        print(addi)
    else: print('Not available')

check()
```